# htaccess RewriteRule not taking effect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, opencart2.x

I want Apache to internally redirect this URL to this. I am using .htaccess file.

http://inaden.dev:8888/products -> http://inaden.dev:8888/index.php?route=products/products
Here is what I have tried but it is giving me 404

```
RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule    ^products/([0-9]+)/?$    /index.php?route=products/products    [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
```

Comment: Your rule is targeting `products/` plus some number and a trailing slash, it won't fire for just `/products`

Comment: @Pekka웃 oh! That did the trick.

Comment: @tekesteg Put the solution as answer below. Keep the erroneous code in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule is targeting `products/` plus some number and a trailing slash, it won't fire for just `/products`. So I fixed the problem by removing the number matching pattern. The working solution is

```
 RewriteRule    ^products/   /index.php?route=products/products    [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
```